# Ways to clear cache from outside rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails 3, I use `caches_page` in controllers to cache a whole html page on the filesystem. I have two different applications (production app and manager app) connecting to the same database. Suppose I am creating a report in the manager app. I would like to clear the cached reports/index view on the production app (running on a different EC2 instance). What is the best way to do that? Right now, I have the cache expiring every 12 hours but I wonder is there is a neat way to clear the cache upon an event.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to expire it yourself like this:-

```
expire_page :controller => 'javascripts', :action => 'dynamic_states', :format => 'js'
```

expire page caching for a given controller's action. Also, make note that page caching and action caching are going to be removed from Rails 4.

Comment: This is from inside the application, I'm asking from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the cache from the console like this:

```
rails runner -e production Rails.cache.clear
```